# Trying to understand class and instance

Tags: haskell

I'm half way through 'real world haskell' and thought I'd have a go at writing my first code. Didn't get very far...

Basically, I thought I'd try and implement an array syntax for doubles and double lists so I can do numerical calculations on lists. Am I right in thinking that 'class' is like a generic function in CLOS? I made a 'class' with a function arplus to add arrays and scalars, and made it work for scalars. Now I don't know how to do the same for lists. (Doing the calculation is easy, I just don't know what to put in place of 'Double' for the list version).

```
class Narray a where
    arplus :: a -> a -> a

instance Narray Double where
    arplus a b =  a + b
```

Then, how do I do mixed versions? Array-scalar and scalar array?

Will I need something like:

```
class Narray a where
   arplus :: a -> b -> a
```

instead?

As an example of the code I'm trying to write, see the sbcl code below:
(Note - I've done this with arrays in lisp, but I was doing it in lists in haskell as they're typed. Doesn't really matter in terms of the question 'though.)

```
;; Generic add for arrays and scalar
(defgeneric .+ (a b))

;; Scalar-scalar
(defmethod .+ ((a double-float) (b double-float)) (+ a b))

;; Array-array
(defmethod .+ ((a SB-KERNEL::SIMPLE-ARRAY-DOUBLE-FLOAT) 
       (b SB-KERNEL::SIMPLE-ARRAY-DOUBLE-FLOAT))
     (dotimes (i (array-total-size a))
        (setf (row-major-aref a i) 
        (+ (row-major-aref a i)
           (row-major-aref b i)))) a)

;; Array-scaler
(defmethod .+ ((a SB-KERNEL::SIMPLE-ARRAY-DOUBLE-FLOAT) (b double-float))
  (dotimes (i (array-total-size a))
      (setf (row-major-aref a i) 
        (+ (row-major-aref a i)
           b))) a)

;; Scalar-array
(defmethod .+ ((a double-float) (b SB-KERNEL::SIMPLE-ARRAY-DOUBLE-FLOAT))
  (dotimes (i (array-total-size b))
      (setf (row-major-aref b i) 
        (+ a 
           (row-major-aref b i)))) b)


;; Just to demo the code
(defun indgen (n) 
  (let ((r (make-array n :element-type 'double-float)))
    (dotimes (i n)
      (setf (row-major-aref r i) (coerce i 'double-float))) r))


* (load "arrays.lisp")

T
* (.+ (indgen 6) 10d0)

#(10.0d0 11.0d0 12.0d0 13.0d0 14.0d0 15.0d0)
* (.+ (indgen 6) (indgen 6))

#(0.0d0 2.0d0 4.0d0 6.0d0 8.0d0 10.0d0)
*
```

Comment: As a side note, I find Real World Haskell works really well when you use [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) to complement the material.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not going to play well with haskell's "say what you mean" philosophy.  Array-array addition (zipping) is a different concept from scalar-array addition (mapping). So you will want two separate operators.  Current convention uses `^` on the side of the vector argument: eg. `^+^` for array-array, and `+^` for scalar-array.

Comment: AFAIK Haskell doesn't support multiple dispatch on types, you can write something like `class Narray a b c where   arplus :: a -> b -> c` but then you will have to mark all types explicitly.

Comment: @adamax: Marking all types explicitly isn't necessary; merely that all types be known. If you write something like `arplus True () ++ "abc"`, it will infer `Bool -> () -> String` just fine. The problem is specifying that for each particular `a` and `b`, there's only one valid `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't answer the whole question, but for the list version, I got this to work:

```
main = [1, 2, 3] `arplus` [4, 5, 6]

class Narry a where
    arplus :: a → a → a

instance (Num a) ⇒ Narry [a] where
    arplus = zipWith (+)
```

I also tried turning (Num a) => [a] into an instance of Num, which had some nice results.

```
instance (Num a) ⇒ Num [a] where
    (+) = zipWith (+)
    (*) = zipWith (*)
    (-) = zipWith (-)
    negate = map negate
    abs    = map abs
    signum = map signum
    fromInteger = repeat∘fromInteger
```

You can try it out just like this

```
main = do print $ [1, 2, 3] * 3   -- [3, 6, 9]
          print $ 3 * [1, 2, 3]   -- [3, 6, 9]
          print $ 3 - [2, 4, 6]   -- [-1, 1, 3]
          print $ [2, 4, 6] + 7   -- [9, 11, 13]
          print $ abs [-2, 4, -3] -- [2, 4, 3]
          print $ [1, 2, 3] + [4.3, 5.5, 6.7] -- [5.3, 7.5, 9.7]
          print $ [1, 2, 3] * [3, 4, 5] -- [3, 8, 15]
```

Of course, if you want to do Double arithmetic with lists, then you'll have to write definitions for some more stuff. I am not sure what the extent of my definition here can do, though I suspect it's not much more than what I've demonstrated.

Also, this isn't the only way to make lists of Nums an instance of Num; there are probably better choices than zipWith for (*).

[EDIT] Making lists an instance of Fractional is trivially easy and adds some more handy functinality.

```
instance (Fractional a) => Fractional [a] where
    recip = map recip
    fromRational = repeat . fromRational
```

This makes list-with-fractional interactions possible, and divide works auto-magically!

```
ghci> [3, 6, 9] / 3
[1.0,2.0,3.0]
ghci> 9 / [1, 2, 3]
[9.0,4.5,3.0]
ghci> 1.2 + [0, 1, 2]
[1.2,2.2,3.2]
```

With great power comes great responsibility; only use these if you need them. If you don't need this behavior, then it's nice to have the compiler yell at you when you try to invoke `+` on a number and a list.

Answer (score 3):

> Basically, I thought I'd try and implement an array syntax for doubles and double lists so I can do numerical calculations on lists. Am I right in thinking that 'class' is like a generic function in CLOS?

Haskell's type classes are a means of implementing what's sometimes called "ad-hoc polymorphism", meaning that a function can operate on multiple types but do different things for each one. They're not completely comparable to anything in most other languages, but from what little I know of it CLOS's "generic functions" sound pretty similar.

> Then, how do I do mixed versions? Array-scalar and scalar array?

I assume your arrays and scalars are of different types--which obviously poses a problem because type classes have a single type parameter. If you're using GHC, there's a language extension `MultiParamTypeClasses` that does... exactly what it says, basically.

Unfortunately it can be kind of a pain in practice for various reasons, but in this case the problem is that you want the mixed version to work for either argument order, but the result needs to be an array for both. The most direct way to do that is to make the result a third type parameter--but then Haskell can't know that `arplus` applied to an array and a scalar is an array, since type parameters are independent of each other. To deal with this, other extensions exist, but things can get complicated quickly for some tasks.

Now, I'm a bit too rusty with lisps to be sure I'm reading your example correctly, but here's a stab at what I think you want:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Narray a b c | a b -> c where
    arplus :: a -> b -> c

instance Narray Double Double Double where 
    arplus = (+)

instance Narray Double [Double] [Double] where 
    arplus x = map (x +)

instance Narray [Double] Double [Double] where 
    arplus x y = map (+ y) x

instance Narray [Double] [Double] [Double] where 
    arplus = zipWith (+)
```

You can look up the extensions I've used in GHC's documentation for further details.

That said, please take the above as an example of how to do simple multiple-dispatch style overloading, not as necessarily a good idea in practice--as @luqui's comment says, this type class conflates operations that are conceptually different, and does so to little benefit.

I'm not sure if a discussion of better overall design would be useful to you, but suffice it to say that in this case I wouldn't bother with type classes at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer camccann. I think maybe your last comment says it all. When you're learning a new language (well an interesting one), very often the hardest part is learning a new way to think. The fact that you've had to add all those extensions suggests to me that I've thought about this all wrong and that I'm fighting rather than writing haskell. What would be the correct thought process here to make something for operators for scalars and lists?